# hide reply link from comment in drupal

Tags: drupal

How does one hide a link in drupal? I am guessing hook_link_alter(&$links, $node, $comment=null) does the trick. A working example would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Flatcomments module](http://drupal.org/project/flatcomments) allows you to hide the reply link on comments.